# Sqlite empty cursor error?

Tags: android, sqlite

Normaly, this code working very well. But, if "cursor" is empty, there is an error in main.class. I tried a lot of thing. But, I didn't success. Please help to solve way.

---- database.class ----

```
  public List<Integer> count_a() {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String selectQuery = "select book, count(date) from myTAB WHERE (date>'" + 0 + "') group by book"; 
// if result is empty, there is an error in main.class.
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}
```

---- main.class ----

```
 private void load_data() {
    Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());

    List<Integer> co_a = db.count_a(); // error is here

    Integer[] co_b = new Integer[co_a.size()];
    co_b = co_a.toArray(co_b);

    List_Row adapter = new List_Row(this, co_b);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvStat);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Failure 1

```
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0 || cursor == null) {
                list.add(0);
            } else {
                list.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            }
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Failure 2

```
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
                list.add(0);
            }else {
                list.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            }
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Failure 3

```
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                list.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            } else {
                list.add(0);
            }
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Failure 4

```
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                list.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            } else {
                list.add(0);
            }
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Failure 5

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor.isBeforeFirst()){
        do {
            list.add(0);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: _I need to use null/empty/zero.. cursor_ to do what ? You can't read any of those.

Comment: `while (cursor.moveToNext()) {...}`

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

If the cursor contains no data, `moveToFirst()` returns false. So add any special empty cursor handling to an `else` branch of your `if (cursor.moveToFirst())` conditional in your first snippet:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
    }
    while (cursor.moveToNext());
} else {
    // whatever you'd like to do in case of no data
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't solve, again. Could you please show me an example on my codes.

Comment: I renewed my question. Could you please look at it again.